# Does rsnapshot save binary diffs?

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot, diff, binary

I use rsnapshot for some years under Kubunt/Linux. But I am not sure how it (and underlying rsync) handles binary diffs: Image a large Thunderbird mailbox file or a 10 MB jpg photo and I change the EXIF data by adding a tag or a rating. What does rsnaphot do:

- copy the new file (10 MB) completly or
- only add the new EXIF data of new bytes?

If rsnapshot does not handle this binary diffs what tools do? rdiff-backup?

Comment: From the man page: "The amount of space required is roughly the size of one full backup, plus a copy of each additional file that is changed."

Answer (score 1):

It will copy the new file completely in the sense it will write a complete new file, but it can detect changes and only transmit these over the network.

Writing only diffs is not possible as traditional filesystems (e.g. `extX`) don't support these kind of diffs and every backup set is supposed to contain all files (mostly hardlinked in).

Comment: The saved network bandwidth in not that importand as the "unnecessary" additional space needed on the backup harddisk.

Comment: That's not the assumption that `rsync` makes. For that, look into modern file systems like ZFS or btrfs.

Comment: Are there other tools that only save the diff?